# Setting a property on a target object only if it exists in a source object, using a helper function

Tags: php

I'm writing a piece of data processing code that often has to set a property on a target object to the value of a property of a source object, but only if that property exists in the source object, like so:

```
if (property_exists($source, 'something')) {
    $target->other = $source->something;
}
```

(I don't use `isset()` because `null` values should also be passed on.)

Repeating the above all over the code would be a pain. Right now I'm using this function to do it:

```
function set_if_exists($target, string $targetProperty, $source, string $sourceProperty)
{
    if (property_exists($source, $sourceProperty)) {
        $target->$targetProperty = $source->$sourceProperty;
    }
}
```

which for the example above would be

```
set_if_exists($target, 'other', $source, 'something');
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without having to name the properties as strings? Ideally I would like to be able to do something like

```
set_if_exists($target->other, $source->something);
```

but I have no idea how to achieve this. Is it even possible?

Comment: I have changed the example code to use `property_exists` instead of `array_key_exists`, which is more correct (the latter works, but is discouraged by the documentation). However, the question itself is about the helper function and avoiding passing property names as strings, NOT the actual checking if a property exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that this is not possible. There does not seem to be any mechanism in PHP that would allow you check for the existence of a (potentially deep) property, the way that the `isset()` builtin or `??` can.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_key_exists`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) only works on arrays, you are using objects. You should use the [`property_exists`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function to know if an object has a specific property.

You cannot do this the way you want to because a non-existing property will always return `null`, so there is no way to know if the property exists or not from the value.

Comment: I have changed the example to use `property_exists` as this indeed more correct (I was relying on backwards compatible behaviour of `array_key_exists`), but the question stands.